# What does a "WARNING: did not see LOP_CKPT_END" message mean on SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The above error message comes up just before SQL Server marks the database as "Suspect" and refuses to open it. Does anyone know what the message means and how to fix it? I think it's a matter of grabbing the backup, but would be nice if it was possible to recover the data.

I've had a look at the [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306366) but there are no transactions to resolve.

Comment: Halo, just want to know, how do you solve the problem, cause I have the same problem about warning did not see LOP_CKPT_END and feeling stress cause I don't have any backup for the last 5 months and I need the data inside my database to create report that will be used in 2 days more.

I don't have enough time to input the data from the last 5 months.It's just really a huge pile of data and process..

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I just had to accept the hit and lose the local cache. In my case there was an underlying disk failure that left the db unrecoverable. I'm sure that's not what you want to hear though. :-( Try the checkdb and logging options though, they certainly helped me narrow down the options. You may have more luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it means your distributed transaction coordinator failed to start correctly when bringing the SQL Server online.

please refer to this [ASP.NET forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1122541/1756522.aspx) and [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306366)

Depending on the level of logging, you should be able to take the last known backup and slowly recover the logs using point in time recovery techniques to slowly bring the database up to the point right before failure began.

Comment: It's not the server itself that's failing, I have other databases on the server that are online, it's just this one database. The database is used as a local cache so there's no backups to recover from :-(

Answer (score 0):

run checkdb to find out why it's been marked as suspect and see if it can be recovered without any data loss (win)